# Zend PHP - sqlsrv insert and Select_Scope() with fetchOne

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, zend-db

I am creating a website using PHP and Zend Framework. I am uisng the sqlsrv adaptor to talk to my database. I am trying to write an insert query and also store the ID of the new row. I have written an SQL query like this:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();               
$id = $db->fetchOne("
    INSERT INTO    MyTable
    (Title, CreatedBy, Created, LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdated)
    SELECT  'MY Title',
        UserTable.UserId,
        CONVERT(datetime, '".$this->details["Created"]."', 120),
        UserTable.UserId,
        CONVERT(datetime, '".$this->details["LastUpdated"]."', 120)
    FROM    UserTable
    WHERE   UserName = '".$this->details["CreatedBy"]."'
    SELECT  CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int) AS Id"
);
```

but it generates this error:

```
'Zend_Db_Statement_Sqlsrv_Exception' with message 'The active result for the query contains no fields.
```

How can I avoid this error and run this query and retreive the inserted row Id?

Comment: if you really want to use SQL you can use [Zend_Db_Statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the wrong method here.

You should be using the [`insert()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.insert)  method of Zend_Db_Table:-

```
$table = new Zend_DB_Table(array('name' => 'mytable', primary => 'myPrimaryKey'));
$data = array()// of data to be inserted
$id = $table->insert($data);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using methods like insert() as I am much more confident using pure MS SQL statements. Is it really necesary to use the insert function? How can I replicate the query I posted?

Comment: Zend_Db isn't designed to be used like that. I'm sure there is a way around it, but it isn't good practice to bypass these methods and I've never needed to, so I can't help you with that sorry. Why use a framework and them not learn to use it properly though?